# XFBML button doesn't appear

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-like

**Situation:** I am running my website on wordpress. I have installed the "Simple Facebook Connect - Base" plugin and configured it by getting the API key for my website. Then I inserted the like button on my own at my own preferred place in the page using i-frame. It worked fine.

**Problem:** But I thought to try the XFBML version. I loaded their JS SDK as said [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/). But now, when I try to use the `fb:like` tag, nothing appears. Chrome's javascript console tells me that the div in which I wrote the XFBML tag is of zero height.

**Question:** How do I get through this? Is there anywhere that I went wrong.

Comment: Did you include fb namespace? `<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">`

Comment: yes i already did that. in fact, the SFC plugin does that automatically. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you are calling [FB.XFBML.parse](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse) either on the whole document, or the elements that you want to be parsed for XFBML.  The old JS library used to do this automatically, but in the new one you have to do it manually.